# Java vs Qt-Qml for rapid,fluid UI designing

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, qml

I have experience in designing UIs with qml and had a good experience creating fluid UIs in almost no time.

I wanted to know if there is a similar toolkit available for Java which could match qml in terms of-

1. Ease of use.
2. Rich 'look and feel' which qml offers.
3. Rapid development

Answer (score 2):

### [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) is the closest match

Somewhere on the Internet I even read about QtQuick (QML+Javascript) being JavaFX supposedly '*done right*'. This is because the syntax of the original [JavaFX Language is very similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX_Script). Also there are tools like the [Scene Builder](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/) that are similar to Qt Quick Designer. Beware JavaFX is kind of dead. And also the *new* JavaFX is not JSON-based but XML-based and more similar to XAML.

### Android SDK is another choice

With all the momentum Android has gained you are very safe with choosing it's whole suite to design. And Android needs no further explanation, Android Studio has lot's of things to ease development.

Comment: _Beware JavaFX is kind of dead._ Why do you think so?

Comment: It's Market share is minimal, and shrinking: https://betterprojectsfaster.com/guide/java-full-stack-report-2022-11/fe-mobile/

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@kevmuhuri/top-five-libraries-for-creating-gui-on-embedded-linux-5ce03903be32) on GUI libraries for embedded and came across [TotalCross](https://totalcross.com/). It uses a Java API which is quite versatile and modern. They're planning to release a [tool](https://yourapp.totalcross.com/knowcode-app) to port UIs in Android XML to TotalCross. This will make it easier to prototype UIs using Android Studio. Their VM is quite optimised and is even deployed on embedded platforms like [Toradex](https://www.toradex.com/support/partner-network/services/200011/totalcross). It's dual-licensed under LGPLv2.1 and commercial licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Most popular Java UI frameworks SWT and Swing are similar to Qt Widgets. I know the only one which brings declarative style of UI development in the Java World - E4/XWT. But it looks more like Microsoft WPF than Qt QML and I did not try it in commercial projects.

Comment: Pavel, swing will give that native widget look and feel that Qt Qidgets provide, but I wanted the kind of fluid UI qml is capable of producing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool (at least I don't know for it).

Only solution I see here is to use [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and combine QML with Java.

Answer (score -1):

I am working on this open source project to use Android XML to build GUI apps to run on iOS, Android, raspberry pi, etc, using [totalcross](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross) as the engine to render the XML on the device.

https://github.com/TotalCross/KnowCodeXML